# Complicated Mysql Query? Summing Values when on same side in same match

Tags: mysql, sql

```
  heroname  dmg    matchid  side
1 Fiora     700    match1   side1
2 Vayne     850    match1   side1
3 Katarina  300    match1   side1
4 Riven     200    match1   side2
5 Katarina  12390  match2   side1
6 Fiora     200    match3   side2
7 Vayne     500    match3   side2
8 Katarina  800    match3   side2
```

My query should sum DMGs when Fiora, Vayne and Katarina's when they are on the same side in a match.

If user types Fiora Vayne and Katarina in input,the site should show:

```
Heros                 DMG
Fiora Vayne Katarina 3350
```

3350 <= sum of row 1 2 3 6 7 8 dmgs.

2nd "Katarina"(5th row) didnt count because it was alone in another match. There were no Fiora and Vayne in its side.

If user types Riven Fiora Katarina in input form

No result should be showed because they are not on same side. Riven was on side 2 while fiora and katarina was on side 1.

How can i do this..

Its too complicated for me. My english is not enough to tell the problem properly with words. I hope you can understand what i want. Im stuck with this, i cant do it. I hope i dont get many downvotes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```sql
SELECT 'Fiora, Vayne, Katarina' AS heroes, 
       SUM(sum_dmg)
FROM (
  SELECT SUM(dmg) AS sum_dmg
  FROM mytable
  WHERE heroname  IN ('Fiora', 'Vayne', 'Katarina')
  GROUP BY matchid, side
  HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT heroname) = 3) AS t
```

The subquery uses grouping in order to identify matches having all specified players on the same side. It returns the `SUM` of `dmg` values for all of these players. The outer query just calculates the total sum.

**Edit:**

For a more generic solution you can use `GROUP_CONCAT` as suggested by @Gordon:

```sql
SELECT heroes, 
       SUM(sum_dmg)
FROM (
  SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT heroname ORDER BY heroname) AS heroes,
         SUM(dmg) AS sum_dmg
  FROM mytable
  GROUP BY matchid, side
  HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT heroname) = 3) AS t
GROUP BY heroes
```

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/102df8/2)

Comment: You should add `group_concat(distinct heroname order by heroname)` to the inner query so you get the list of heros as well.

Comment: @GordonLinoff `HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT heroname) = 3` implies that *all three hardcoded* heroes are returned.

Comment: Thank you very much! What should i do when i want to list every 3 hero combination without user input?

Comment: @YusufDevranlı Add the `GROUP_CONCAT` as suggested by Gordon. Also add `GROUP BY heroes` in the outer query.

Comment: @GiorgosBetsos can u give me the full code i dont know where to put them in outer query inner query i dont know much mysql

Comment: @GiorgosBetsos it works on sql fiddle but somehow second code is not working in my page. idk why:(/ 

$veri=mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {

echo $veri['heroes']; 
echo $veri['SUM(sum_dmg))'];
 it doesnt give any errors just nothing. i changed 3 to 2


my original table is a bit different heroname => champions, mytable => league, matchid => mac but its not working when i change them its just doesnt work.

Comment: @GiorgosBetsos i changed 3 to 5 then it started working on my orginal table but its just working for 5 heros. every side has 5 heros in my table. i wanted to get all 3 hero combinations

Comment: @YusufDevranlı You can try changing `=3` to `>=3`.